# Python: Print repeated value in a string

Tags: python

I have to write a simple program in python 3.6 that takes the user input and computes the value of `n+n*n+n*n*n+n*n*n*n`.

So if the user enters 7, then the following should be printed to the console `7+7*7+7*7*7+7*7*7*7 =  2800`.

How do i accomplish this with the print function?

So far i have tried the following:

```
input_int = int(input("Please enter a value: "))

result_int = input_int + input_int * input_int + input_int * input_int * input_int +  input_int * input_int * input_int * input_int

print(input_int + input_int * input_int + input_int * input_int * input_int +  input_int * input_int * input_int * input_int, " = ", result_int)
```

and doesn't give me what i want.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: You can use convert the `input_int` to string, and use `+` to concatenate them.

Comment: Please show more context. Where does `input_int` come from? Where is your calculation for `result_int`?

Comment: Anyway, of course it doesn't give you what you want - there is nothing in your code, for example, that attempts to produce `+` or `*` symbols in the output. Think through the steps of the problem logically.

Comment: First try to write the code that just computes the value that results from doing the math. Then try to write the code that displays the expression, by displaying literal `+` and `*` and `=` symbols with the input value in between. Then put it together.

Comment: I am coming from C# and I was wondering if there is something like this in python: `Console.WriteLine("{0}+{0}*{0}+{0}*{0}*{0}+{0}*{0}*{0}*{0}={1}", n, n + n * n + n * n * n + n * n * n * n);`

Answer (score 2):

```
input_int = int(input("Please enter a value: "))
result_int = input_int + input_int * input_int + input_int * input_int * input_int +  input_int * input_int * input_int * input_int
input_string = f'{input_int} + {input_int} * {input_int} + {input_int} * {input_int} + {input_int} * {input_int} + {input_int} * {input_int} + {input_int} = {result_int}'

print(input_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of help as this seems like a H/W assignment.

You need to convert the integers into strings and handle the math symbols as strings...  So something like this...

```
In [2]: my_int = 7                                                              

In [3]: # convert to a string...                                                

In [4]: my_int = str(my_int)                                                    

In [5]: print(my_int,'+',my_int,'*')                                            
7 + 7 *
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your result is already stored in result_int, and the 'n' is stored in input_int.

> `print(input_int + input_int * input_int + input_int * input_int * input_int + input_int * input_int * input_int * input_int, " = ",result_int)`

This wouldn't work, as you are directly printing the value.

You need to use something like:

`print(input_int + '+' + input_int + '*' + input_int + '+' + input_int + '*' + input_int + '*' + input_int + '+' + input_int + '*' + input_int + '*' + input_int + '*' + input_int, " = ",result_int)`

This would give the desired output.

Comment: Or can we use a for loop to print this iteratively?

Comment: Yes, we can use the for loop for it also.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of iteration is fixed to 4 then you can iterate from 1 to 5 or if your iteration is dynamic you can replace 5 with your variable.

```
input_int = int(input("Please enter a value: "))
out = 0
string = ''
for i in range(1,5):
    string += (str(input_int)+"*")*i+"+"
    out += pow(input_int, i)

string = string.replace("*+", " + ")[:-2]+" = "

print(string+str(out))
```

Explain:

for is iterating from 1 to 5 which results in 4 times iteration.

> string += (str(input_int)+"*")*i+"+"
> which will create a string display like 7 + 7*7*+ 7*7*7*+

Here extra '*' and '+' sign need to be removed.

> out += pow(input_int, i)

Pow is the default python function to calculate the square of a number like `pow(7,2)`

Replace extra '*' and '+' with `replace` and add '=' at the end.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the latest comments, I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
x = 7
result = 7 + (7 * 7) + (7 * 7 * 7) + (7 * 7 * 7 * 7)
print(f'{x} + {x} * {x} + {x} * {x} * {x} + {x} * {x} * {x} * {x} = {result}')
```

**Output**

```
7 + 7 * 7 + 7 * 7 * 7 + 7 * 7 * 7 * 7 = 2800
```

Python Documentation: [Formatted String Literals (f-strings)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little math.

```
>>> n = 7
>>> (n**5 - 1) // (n - 1) - 1
2800
```